# Ruby on Rails jquery ajax validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I'm working on ruby on rails and i'm an absolute beginner. 
My question is: 
I have a user signup form and I would like to verify whether the username already exists and return the status in json format. I would like to achieve this by using the jquery ajax, how do i do this.

```
def check_user
 @user=User.find_by_username(params[:username'])
 respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.json { render json: !@user }
  end
end
```

my application.js:

```
$("#user_name").change(function(){
  //How do i call my check_user action and get a response
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at validates_uniqueness_of [in the API documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: All i want to do is pass the input field value of a form to my users_controller action method called check_user which cheks whether the usernane exists or not and respond it via json using jquery/ajax

Comment: Any reason you MUST do it this way rather than using ActiveRecord's built in validation?  Try to create a new user, the model will throw an exception if it's not unique, catch that exception and send a response to the user

Comment: well i am aware of that, but i want it the jquery/ajax way!

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by JSON format and if you like to use some sort of validation. I recommend using [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/263-client-side-validations)

Comment: All i want to do is pass the input field value of a form to my users_controller action method called check_user which cheks whether the usernane exists or not and respond it via json using jquery ajax